# TwoFer program Bug

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, google-closure-compiler, decompiler

I ran into a problem while writing the TwoFer program
[image]

This is the program's code

```
public static class TwoFer
{
    public static string Speak()
    {
        return "One for you, one for me.";
    }
    public static  Speak(string h)
    {

        if (h == "Bob")
        {
            return "One for Bob, one for me.";
        }
        else
        {
            return "One for Alice, one for me.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear, you didn't define a return type for `Speak(string h)` - what is confusing you?

Comment: Is your problem with error or your code? If error, which one of this 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Speak(string)` method is missing a return type:

```cs
public static String Speak(string h)
// Here ------^
```